# Horizontal GridView in android without external library

Tags: android, gridview

I refer to many examples but it is not working (horizontally scrolling)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_imgview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hacker.gallarydemo.imgview">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/title_horizontalScrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true">

            <GridView
                android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:numColumns="6"
                android:columnWidth="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                 />
    </HorizontalScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout file. I want horizontal gridview but it doesn't scroll horizontally. What changes should I make here to scroll horizontally?

Comment: What is the purpose of `GridView` inside the `HorizontalScrollView` if you only want horizontal scroll?

Comment: because it doesnt scroll...how to scroll it??

Comment: Try to give rotation 270 to the gridview and gridviewitem rotation 90, and do some little design or style work out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `recyclerview` with `GridLayoutManager`

`GridLayoutManager` will be attached to `recyclerview` in order to generate horizontal grids. Here is small snippet -

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false); // 2 will define number of row.
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

reference: [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)

Comment: Nope, I think you should go with `recyclerview` as it has good advantage. And its is pretty simple as well.

Comment: i know recyclerview is simple and flexible, but for few reasons i have to use gridview ... if gridview has scrolling property then why its not working horizontally??? it works fine vertically